# Why Do Singers Prefer Back Vowel Non-Lexical Vocables?

Tags: vowels, frontness-backness

Singers more often sing "oohs" than they do "eehs". Why is that?

It's exemplified in this article: https://qz.com/767812/millennial-whoop/ .

I've listened to a fair amount of 50's, 60's, and 70's songs, and it seems to hold true in the past too.

Comment: Probably back vowels demand less constriction than front vowels? You could make a similar point regarding consonants, I suppose - don't singers prefer laterals - lalarala - over stops or fricatives - fafatafa?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really a linguistic question. You might like to visit the [music.se] site.

Comment: It's a question with a known answer in phonetics, but I don't know the answer. Something to do with formants and the singer's formant at around 3K. Musicalinguist will surely know.

Comment: I doubt that it's true for all singers in all cultures.  I think it's due to the influence of Italian opera and "Italianate" singing.  One is taught to raise the roof of the mouth, and try to produce the feeling of a yawn, to increase the resonance of the voice.